# summing two colums of a table and display in html table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sum two columns of the same table row by row but my code gives me the total of the two tables.

```
id  Price 1   price 2 
1   20          20
2   40          30
```

i want to sum the sum of each row and display in html table looking like this

```
id Total
1    40
2    70
```

This is my sql code

```
Select sum( price1+price2) from table
```

Comment: One of the simplest queries. Have tried a bit of it? Mind it `SUM` is an aggregate function. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (price1+price2) as total_price FROM table
```

[**SUM**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) is an aggregation function : it aggregates all records found and does the sum.

price1 + price2 sums this two columns for each record separatly.

Comment: Please explain the reason why his code didn't work and yours worked. Just try to refine the knowledge base regarding this of the `PO`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove SUM it will aggregate all

```
Select ( price1+price2) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id AS Id,ISNULL(price1,0)+ISNULL(price2,0) AS Total from table
```

Comment: "ISNULL" will handle if any column value is null then it consider as "0"